# I want find a good mysql Manager use on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, software-rec, mysql

On Windows, i use SQLyog. And I am new to Ubuntu.

Is there any mysql manager programs as good as SQLyog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL now offer MySQL Workbench, which may or may not be what you are looking for.

I tried it on Windows, and it suited my needs to the tee.

http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/#downloads

Comment: I would also recommend this program. It's managed by oracle and is directly designed for MySQL. A very feature rich program.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Administrator](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html).

`sudo apt-get install mysql-admin`

It is a very GUI driven tool but also very well done. I've used it and for my needs it has been perfect. Though, I'll admit that my needs are rather simple, and probably don't scratch the surface of what this tool can do.

*[update] - It appears this will be deprecated in favor of the [Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/), and there does appear to be a Ubuntu build available.*

Comment: i installed mysqladmin but i want use tool.

Comment: You may also go for MySql Query Browser along with MySQL Administrator, both of them are available in Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite by far is [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com).  They have a free lite version that you can use that will probably do everything you need it to.  The great thing is that the new version works across multiple databases.

Answer (score 0):

I use SQLyog in wine on Ubuntu.  I've not had any issues with it.

Edit: here is the link to use [SQLyog](http://faq.webyog.com/content/31/71/en/can-i-use-sqlyog-with-the-wine-windows-emulator-on-linux.html) on wine.